# What is correct, "a club day" or "the club day"?

Tags: usage, determiners

> Do you know if Monday is **a/the** club day?

Should I use *a* or *the*?

Club days are days when we do our club activities. As Monday is usually not a/the club day but the next one will be the early May bank holiday, I simply would like to ask this question on the club forum.

Comment: Welcome! Please edit to tell more about the meaning that you're looking for. There could be situations where either is appropriate.

Comment: @AndyBonner edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there are many "club days," "a" is probably the best choice, just as you might use it with a day of the week: "Tomorrow is **a Monday**."

If there had already been a discussion that was focusing on one particular "club day," then "the" could be an option:

> "There's one club day every month. When is May's club day?"
> "The club day [meaning 'for May'] is the 15th."

Answer (score 0):

I think the right choice is "the", because the club day you mentioned is specific, and the club day is your consensus.